# flutter mix optional and named arguments in a function

Tags: flutter, function, arguments, option-type, named

I have a simple problem but I cannot find an answer to my question.

Is there a way to mix : optional arguments with default value and required named arguments in a flutter function ?

I need something like that but this exemple doesn't works in flutter.

```
 Future<void> getNationalRanking({required String connectedUserId}, [countryCode = "FR"]) async {
// blabla 
}
```

it might be a stupid syntax that I don't know.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named parameters are already optional if you don't make them required and either make them nullable or provide a default value.  For example:

```dart
Future<void> getNationalRanking({
  required String connectedUserId,
  String? countryCode,
}) async {
  countryCode ??= "FR";
  ...
}
```

or:

```dart
Future<void> getNationalRanking({
  required String connectedUserId,
  String countryCode = "FR",
}) async {
  ...
}
```

Your example attempts to mix named parameters with optional *positional* parameters, but using both is not allowed.  From the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters):

> A function can have any number of *required positional* parameters. These can be followed either by *named* parameters or by *optional positional* parameters (but not both).

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1076.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I need to mix required named parameters and optional named parameters. Is it a problem ?

Comment: @MaximeArnould No, it's not a problem.  That's what the examples I showed do.

Comment: Ok thanks again for the clarifications I didn't had the syntax 

Comment: @jamesdlin Any insight on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74539877/how-can-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-based-on-the-hebrew-language-in-dart ?