# How can I sort a list alphabetically based on the Hebrew language in Dart?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sorting, hebrew

#### Context

In Dart, if I have a list:

```
final myList = ['b', 'a'];
```

and I wanted to sort it alphabetically, I would use:

```
myList.sort(
      (String a, String b) => a.compareTo(b),
    );
```

The output of `myList` is now:

```
['a', 'b']
```

Now, this works on letters that are in the *English* alphabet.

#### Question

But if I have a list that's in Hebrew:

```
final unorderedHebAlphabet = ['א', 'ב'];
```

I *can't* sort it as above using with:

```
 unorderedHebAlphabet.sort((String a, String b) =>
        a.compareTo(b))
```

It doesn't sort.

Expected output, instead of:

```
['א', 'ב']
```

Should be:

```
['ב', 'א']
```

- How can I sort a list Alphabetically in the Hebrew language?

##### Notes

As a reference, the Hebrew alphabet sorted would be in this order:

```
final sortedHebrewAlphabet = [
  'א',
  'ב',
  'ג',
  'ד',
  'ה',
  'ו',
  'ז',
  'ח',
  'ט',
  'י',
  'כ',
  'ל',
  'מ',
  'נ',
  'ס',
  'ע',
  'פ',
  'צ',
  'ק',
  'ר',
  'ש',
  'ת',
];
```

Comment: It seems that the list is actually being printed out backwards with the hebrew text. I am guessing this has something to do with hebrew being read right to left instead of left to right. Notice how there is a space after the comma in the english list, but the space is before the comma in the hebrew list. In other words index 0 is on the right in the hebrew list, but index 0 is on the left in the english list. I can't read hebrew so I have no idea if the list printing out this way makes any sense or not, but that appears to be what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *does* sort (by UTF-16 code units), but it's being shown in an unintuitive way. `final unorderedHebAlphabet = ['א', 'ב'];` seems to be parsed RTL, so in the constructed list, element 0 is `א` and element 1 is `ב`.  That's already the desired order, so sorting it does not change it. (Mixing LTR and RTL text is confusing.)

For example:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var literal = ['א', 'ב'];
  print(literal[0]); // Prints: א
  print(literal[1]); // Prints: ב

  const alef = 'א';
  const bet = 'ב';
  const expectedOrder = [alef, bet];

  const listEquals = ListEquality<String>();
  
  print(listEquals.equals(literal..sort(), expectedOrder)); // Prints: true
  print(listEquals.equals([bet, alef]..sort(), expectedOrder)); // Prints: true
}
```

You also can observe that the elements are printed in the correct order if you prefix output with the Unicode LTR override (U+202D) to force rendering the text as LTR.  Compare:

```dart
const ltr = '\u202D';
print('$expectedOrder');
print('$ltr$expectedOrder');
```

Or you could simply print the elements separately:

```dart
expectedOrder.forEach(print);
```

which prints:

```
א
ב
```

I'm not experienced with dealing with RTL text, but I'd probably avoid mixing LTR and RTL text in code and instead express them as hexadecimal Unicode code points to avoid confusion.

Comment: thank you. But I still need to know how to _print_ it out in the correct order. So, I'll await other answers and accept yours if I don't get any other answers.

Comment: @MendelG I explained how to print the elements in the order you want, but I see that you unaccepted this answer.  Is this incorrect or insufficient?  If so, why?

Comment: Your answer is actually correct. I just want to see other answers. And I will possibly award you the bounty..

Answer (score 0):

It is being printed out in correct order. It's the Console which is printing it in the way it is.

When you save the sorted list into a file and read it again, you get the `אב` characters as first two characters. So they are being written/iterated in right order.

If you print the values one letter per line, you would get desired result. I am not 100% sure how console is handling it, but dart is simply passing it to the `STDOUT` (default console), and console is detecting that the string is actually RTL and printing (or writing to STDOUT) in that way.

I did little fiddling which you can see:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final myList = [
    'א',
    'ב',
    'ג',
    'ד',
    'ה',
    'ו',
    'ז',
    'ח',
    'ט',
    'י',
    'כ',
    'ל',
    'מ',
    'נ',
    'ס',
    'ע',
    'פ',
    'צ',
    'ק',
    'ר',
    'ש',
    'ת'
  ];

  // for (var i in myList) {
  //   print("$i => ${i.runes.toList()}");
  // }

  myList.sort();

  String s = "";

  for (var i in myList) {
    s += i;
  }

  print('$s');

  print(myList.first);

  final file = new File('/Users/rahul/Desktop/string_l/test.txt');
  file.writeAsStringSync(s, flush: true);

  final read = file.readAsStringSync().substring(0, 2);
  print(read);

  // You can also verify by calling print with every element
  for (var i in myList) {
    print(i);
  }
}
```

output

```
אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשת
א
אב
א
ב
ג
ד
ה
ו
ז
ח
ט
י
כ
ל
מ
נ
ס
ע
פ
צ
ק
ר
ש
ת
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'dart:io';

final unorderedHebAlphabet = [
  'ב',
  'ג',
  'ד',
  'ה',
  'ו',
  'ז',
  'ח',
  'ט',
  'י',
  'כ',
  'ל',
  'מ',
  'נ',
  'ס',
  'ע',
  'פ',
  'צ',
  'ק',
  'ר',
  'ש',
  'ת',
  'א'
];


void main() {
  print(unorderedHebAlphabet);
  unorderedHebAlphabet
      .sort((a, b) => a.codeUnitAt(0).compareTo(b.codeUnitAt(0)));
  print(unorderedHebAlphabet);
}
```